# what if someone tries to finish public keys by non-stop creating

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin-core, bitcoin-core-development

Lets say one big company or country start a war against bitcoin and they have very powerful machines. What happens if they starts to create public key all the time? Is it possible to finish all the public keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in theory but it would take so long that neither you, nor I will still be alive by a long shot.

At about 10,000 key pairs per second, with an address space of 2^160, it would take you 50 tredecillion years to finish.

Thats 50,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000 years
To put that into perspective, the age of the universe is about 13,000,000,000 years

Answer (score 1):

yes, it will just take more energy, than the sun can currently provide :-) 
Or otherwise: how to store 2^160 addresses...
Here is a discussion on bitcoin forum:

https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1164265.0

Answer (score 1):

This is technically impossible and economically illogical. If you could check this many addresses, you could also mine bitcoins.

Here are a couple of fun vids:

[Bitcoin 101 - Quindecillions & The Amazing Math Of Bitcoin's Private Keys](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZloHVKk7DHk)

[Ever wonder how Bitcoin (and other cryptocurrencies) actually work?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bBC-nXj3Ng4)

Both discuss the 'size' of the bitcoin address space.